# Does Dropbox sync when computer is asleep or locked?

Tags: sync, sleep, dropbox

I have some pretty big sync's to do, but I can't sit around my computer making sure it's awake and unlocked all day/night.

Does Dropbox sync when the computer is "Locked" or asleep?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if no fans are spinning then no programs are running (at all). As Michael states below it being simply locked as opposed to sleep DB *should* still run.

Comment: Locked...Yes when the computer is in a low power state ( i.e. sleep mode ) no of course not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We don't know what your system is, so I'm a little fuzzy on the definition of 'locked' for you.

Under a Windows OS, if you lock the screen (that is, stay logged in, use Win+L or 'lock' under the start menu to lock it), then yes, Dropbox will continue to run and sync.

Under a Windows OS, 'sleep' means that the computer is off and not running programs, but memory is being held live so that it can wake up very quickly. In this state, NO, dropbox can't sync, because it's not running.

Comment: Thanks. The question was for both OSX and Win7, but I'm sure it works the same for both.

Comment: @CorySimmons - The only question is the definition of lock and sleep - They should be pretty universal terms, but I find that when I make too many assumptions, the universe tends to smack me in the head.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on Windows 10 where drop box didn't seem to sync when locked.  Issue was wireless disconnected when locked to save power.

[See this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/wifi-gets-disconnected-when-screen-is-locked/1e628a4b-92c5-4fa1-8385-ec961699e413?auth=1)

In short, Device Manager -> Right click device, Properties -> Power Management -> Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power

Answer (score 2):

No, it wont, however there are many programs out there to keep your pc awake such as Caffeine.

Caffeine for Mac: [(Direct)](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) [(Mac App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12)
Caffeine for Windows: [(Direct)](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)

Comment: Caffeine for PC: www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/

Comment: Why would you just not turn the sleep function off?

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the original subject on top of @Michael Kohne's answer, there seems to be a pitfall on Mac in terms of lock; in default setting (I'm on OSX 10.9.5), OS might go to sleep during lock. To disable that feature, [see this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76107/how-can-i-keep-my-mac-awake-and-locked).

With my Dropbox on Mac, I found by looking at my [Recent Event](https://www.dropbox.com/events) page on dropbox.com that the sync only happens while I'm at the machine, although I didn't let it sleep before I left (to sync the huge batch of files). The solution above worked for me -- now it syncs while I'm away.